# Заметки на PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Хочу сделать заметки на определенную дату и время через pyqt5, дабы при наступлении нужного времени в windows приходило уведомление, и дабы заметка сохранялась не в виде текстового файла, однако не понимаю как это сделать, искал информацию по данному вопросу в интернете, но к сожалению ничего не нашел, можете помочь это реализовать, пожалуйста

Comment: Оно? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-systray-example.html

Comment: Вот еще либа https://github.com/mohabouje/WinToast

Comment: Gidra покажите что вы уже успели попробовать сделать чтобы решить вопрос.